# How call router navigate method from Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, router

I use Angular 2, SystemJs and ES6 (Not TypeScript).

What do I want? I want navigate to link with Route. What I'm doing

```
// route for exam simple
export let routes = [
    {path: '', name: 'home', component: HomeComponent, terminal: true}, 
    {path: 'auth', name: 'auth', component: AuthComponent}
]
```

It works well if I use [routerLink]. And now I want programmatically use router like this

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'tf-main',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: '<p>home</p><router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})

export class HomeComponent {

    static get parameters() {
        return [[Router]]
    }

    constructor(router) {
        this.router = router;

        // This wrong way!!!! Help!!!!
        this.router.navigateByUrl(['auth']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

just

```
this.router.navigate(['auth']);
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
```

(to ensure the root route `auth` is used)

Comment: The problem is **this.router** has not navigate method

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: I use Angular 2 version 2.0.0.rc4, router 3.0.0.beta1

Comment: Sorry, no idea. https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigate-anchor

Answer (score 5):

How about using this constructor?

```
constructor(
private router: Router){}
```

then

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['auth']);
}
```

I think your error message means you should initialize 'router' correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to me `router.navigateByUrl` accepts only string not array so your syntax should be like this

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
```

or if this is your child route after home th

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/auth');
```

see also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigateByUrl-anchor